# Как реализовать "дотягивание" в CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, coordinator-layout

Есть активити, в нем достаточно простая структура:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <!--Header content-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <RecyclerView/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Все работает отлично, содержимое заголовка прячется при прокрутке списка. Но при этом если остановить прокрутку, то заголовок останется наполовину скрытым. Нужно запретить показывать заголовок в промежуточном состоянии и чтобы в этом случае, он автоматически допрокручивался до либо закрытия, либо открытия.

Как я понимаю, это реализовывается с помощью Behaviour. Нужно ли делать кастомный или же существует что-то готовое для этой цели?

Comment: а к элементу view пробовали дописывать этот параметр? 
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"

Comment: @Сергей эти флаги доступны только для элементов, расположенных внутри `AppBarLayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно заместо `LinearLayout` использовать `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. У него "под капотом" есть данное поведение. Включается оно таком образом:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

---

Важно отметить что данное поведение доступно только при "оборачивании" `CollapsingToolbarLayout` в `AppBarLayout`. Обуславливается это тем, что `Behavior` коллапсинга содержится внутри класса `AppBarLayout`.

Так же важно отметить что `AppBarLayout` должен иметь фиксированную высоту (никаких `wrap_content`).

---

В итоге у вас должна получиться такая иерархия:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="some height">
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">
            <!--Header content-->
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```