# Плавное появление и исчезновение View элемента

Tags: android

Есть разметка

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/customerInfoParent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">


    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...


</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/valuescroll"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

как сделать чтобы при скроле NestedScrollView элемент customerInfoParent скрывался и появлялся как collapse action bar

По примеру из ссылки сделал так:

```
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...


</LinearLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/valuescroll"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

но работает не так хочется. он ходит вместе с скролом т.е. как будто мой LinearLayout внутри скрола, чтобы он появился надо скролить до начало..

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642997/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-coordinatorlayout

Comment: Оберните его в AppBarLayout